# Eigenvalues of a matrix formed by derivatives of a polynomial

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $f=f(x,y)$ be a polynomial with $x\geq 0,\ -2x\leq y\leq -x/2$ (so when $x=1, -2\leq y\leq-1/2$). Denote
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
f_1=&\frac{\partial \ln f}{\partial x}(1,y),\\
f_2=&\frac{\partial \ln f}{\partial y}(1,y),\\
f_{11}=&\frac{\partial^2 \ln f}{\partial x^2}(1,y),\\
f_{22}=&\frac{\partial^2 \ln f}{\partial y^2}(1,y),\\
f_{12}=&\frac{\partial^2 \ln f}{\partial x\partial y}(1,y).
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

Define
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
A=&[2f_1+f_{11}(y+2)](y+2),\\
B=&[2f_2+f_{22}(2y+1)](2y+1),\\
C=&[2(f_2-f_1)+(f_{11}+f_{22}-2f_{12})(y-1)](y-1),\\
D=&f_{12}(y+2)(2y+1),\\
E=&(f_{12}-f_{11})(y+2)(y-1),\\
F=&(f_{22}-f_{12})(2y+1)(y-1).
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

Define a $3\times 3$ symmetric matrix
\begin{equation*}
M=\begin{bmatrix}
A & D & E\\
D & B & F\\
E & F & C\\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}

My question is:

could we show that for ANY polynomial $f$, $M$ is NOT nonnegative-definite? or

could we find *one* polynomial such that $M$ is *nonnegative-definite*?

Comment: Can you tell us more of the background of your question. Where does the form of the matrix come from? Why are there logarithms within the derivatives?

Comment: Thank you very much for your interest. In fact $x,y$ (and $z=-x-y$) are eigenvalues of a matrix with zero trace. I am trying to find a polynomial whose logarithm is subharmonic, which is equivalent to nonnegative-definiteness of $M$.